# CSS3 Animations different results on Chrome/Safari

Tags: css, skew, css-animations

I'm working on a CSS3 Keyframe Animation with a `skew()` transform. I was able to achieve the result I was looking for in Safari 6. However, when I view the page on another Webkit browser, Chrome I am getting a different animation result.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div id="test">
    webkit animation test
</div>
```

CSS

```
#test {
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-animation-name: testBox;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;             /* alternate, normal */
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
}

@-webkit-keyframes testBox /* Safari and Chrome */ {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: skew(70deg,0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: skew(-70deg,0deg);
    }
}
```

Anyone else have this issue?

Comment: works fine for me. what results do you get?

Comment: It works yes, but it seems the animation timing is different between Safari and Chrome. Chrome seems to speed up animation at the beginning and at the end. Whereas, Safari is more uniform timing/speed.